# How we can pass nested Object to PrimeNG Dynamic Table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-table

I have nested object which I want to pass to PrimeNG Dynamic Table but it looks it's not happening . Wherever I have nested object I'm passing it as we usually do but not happening .

Is there any specific rule we need to follow with PrimeNG

.html

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="MyData">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

.ts

```
this.cols = [
    { field: 'NAME', header: 'Name' },
    {field: 'AGE', header: 'Age' },
    {field: 'ADDRESS.POSTCODE', header: 'Post Code' }
    {field: 'ADDRESS.ZIPCODE', header: 'Zip' }
];
```

.JSON

```
[
  {
    "NAME": "ABC",
    "AGE": "000",
    "ADDRESS": {
      "POSTCODE": "00",
      "ZIPCODE": "1212"
    }
  },
  {
    "NAME": "XYZ",
    "AGE": "000",
    "ADDRESS": {
      "POSTCODE": "00",
      "ZIPCODE": "1212"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz or at least share all your TS component please ?

Answer (score 3):

In your component create a function like this:

```
parseFieldInData(data: any, field: string) {
  return field.includes('.')
    ? field.split('.').reduce((acc: any, obj: any) => acc[obj], data)
    : data[field];
}
```

and on html of your component use the function above passing the data and the field like this:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="MyData">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{ parseFieldInData(rowData, col.field) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

this works with nested objects and nested objects inside a nested objects....

Comment: Shouldn't the first parameter "data" in the HTML be rowData though?